# How to use a custom Angular module in different projects

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular-module

I want to create a common module which will contain components like login, sidebar etc and pipes, services, directives.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    InitialsPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class CompanyCommonModule { }
```

Now, I want to use it in other projects like:

```
import { CompanyCommonModule } from 'company-common-module';
```

Comment: Why don't you publish your components as package over npm?

Comment: It has company specific confidential data

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please vote to delete this question as I am unable to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a library to do that: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: We need to create a library within a project. So lets say I have created one library in Project A. After building, it resides within dist folder. For using it (without publishing) in Project B, shall I have to copy it in dist folder of Project B and then use?

Comment: You can just link to the library, best solution would be to use TypeScript path mapping. Generally I would recommend to use angular-cli workspace, you can generate multiple projects and libraries and they share one tsconfig. When you build a library a path mapping will be generated and you can just use `import {..} from 'my-lib` in every project. Here some Info about workspaces: https://angular.io/guide/file-structure

Comment: Thanks for the info